# YouTube gives error on google app engine quota error. but my app hardly make some 100 requests to youtube api

Tags: youtube-api

My application using YouTube api gives me this error response when this is on google app engine

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><errors><error><domain>yt:quota</domain><code>too_many_recent_calls</code></error></errors>
```

But on localhost everything works fine.
This application is in sandbox mode so, hardly any request going to YouTube from the Google App Engine server. 
Frequently i am getting this error. 
please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Do you use your personal API key? If not, start doing so, otherwise your allowed quotas will be very small. If you have your API key, you will be able to check your quota usage in your developer console—and you will be able to check why your quota is exceeded.

Source: https://developers.google.com/youtube/faq#quota, https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started#quota

Comment: in GET requests i use access_token for a YouTube account. Like this.    https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api
/videos/u0RfKhQ63AU/comments?alt=json&v=2&access_token=ya29.AHES6ZSbhXtwinjJTVd3NbRXXXXXXXxxxxxzm5DNj1lVk8                        . Am i missing anything here?

Comment: Are you saying that i have to pass my developer api key along with access_token.i so, what will the parameter for that? like api_key=XXXXX or key=XXX... thanks.

Comment: `access_token` should be enough. If so, you should see your queries in the developer api console, and that would explain what kind of quota you have and how much of it you really use.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions i will check this one.